# Javascript: How to get the right instance of an object from an event handler when their are multiple instances of the object

Tags: javascript, class, onclick, call, instance

I created an object and it works great when I have one instance of the object. This isn't the actual Object, but the concept is the same.

```
function foo(name){
    this.name = name;
}

foo.prototype.CreateElement = function(){
    var newElement = document.createElement("a");

    that = this;

    newElement.onclick = function(){
        that.SayName(this);
    };

    document.getElementsByName("body")[0].appendChild(newElement);
}

foo.prototype.SayName = function(LinkObj){
    alert(this.name);
    LinkObj.href = "http://google.com";
}
```

I was told that by saving the instance of `this` to a variable (in this case `that`), I would still get a reference to the correct object instance for the `SayName` method. This would leave `this` to represent the instance of the element passed in from the `onclick`. This all seems to work properly with only one instance, but when I create multiple instances of the object I end up with the last instance being the instance supplied in the `onclick` event.

I initialize two objects like this

```
var ObjOne = new foo("Ted");
ObjOne.CreateElement();

var ObjTwo = new foo("Steve");
ObjTwo.CreateElement();
```

and when the `onclick` fires for `ObjOne`, I get the object instance for `ObjTwo` and so `this.Name` is set to `Steve`.

Does anyone know how I can get the right object instance when the onclick event fires from various instances? I assume i need to bind the correct instance with `call`, but i'm not really sure how to.

Thanks in advance and hope this wasn't to confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
that = this;
```

You declared `that` without using `var`, which means it is *global*, i.e., all your instances are updating the same global `that` variable. Do this instead:

```
var that = this;
```

Then `that` will be local to each. (That is, local to each closure of the CreateElement function.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SEsLJ/

Also, `document.getElementsByName` should be `document.getElementsByTagName` (assuming you didn't actually give the body a name attribute equal to "body").

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it! The `getElementsByName` mistake was just a typo.